# WPF Style is not applied for a UserControl who is already styled

Tags: wpf

I come to you because I got headaches about control styling for a few hours.
By defining a style to the usercontrol, it doesn't work !

My usercontrol declaration :

```
<uiComponent:NumericTextBox Text="{Binding myProperty}"/>
```

The style I want to apply to :

```
<Style TargetType="uiComponent:NumericTextBox">
   <Setter Property="Background" Value="Black"/>
</Style>
```

Why it doesn't work with the Background property, although it works with the Visibility property !
I tried with TargetType=FrameworkElement, no effect....

My usercontrol is a numerictextbox which define its own style like this :

```
<ResourceDictionary
  xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
  xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
  xmlns:mwt="clr-namespace:Microsoft.Windows.Themes;assembly=PresentationFramework.Aero"
  xmlns:l="clr-namespace:LSX.Space.PropertyUI.NumericTextBox">

    <SolidColorBrush x:Key="CustomTextBox_Background" Color="White" />
    <SolidColorBrush x:Key="CustomTextBox_Foreground" Color="Black" />
    <LinearGradientBrush x:Key="CustomTextBox_Border" StartPoint="0,0" EndPoint="0,1">
        <GradientStop Color="#FFABADB3" Offset="0.05" />
        <GradientStop Color="#FFE2E3EA" Offset="0.07" />
        <GradientStop Color="#FFE3E9EF" Offset="1" />
    </LinearGradientBrush>

    <Style x:Key="{x:Type l:NumericTextBox}" TargetType="{x:Type l:NumericTextBox}">
        <Setter Property="Background" Value="{StaticResource CustomTextBox_Background}" />
        <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="{StaticResource CustomTextBox_Border}" />
        <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{StaticResource CustomTextBox_Foreground}" />
        <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="1" />
        <Setter Property="SnapsToDevicePixels" Value="True" />
        <Setter Property="FocusVisualStyle" Value="{x:Null}"/>
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type l:NumericTextBox}">
                    <Border x:Name="Border"
                      Background="{TemplateBinding Background}"
                      BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}"
                      BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}">
                        <Grid x:Name="LayoutGrid">
                            <ScrollViewer Margin="2" x:Name="PART_ContentHost" />
                        </Grid>
                    </Border>
                    <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                        <!--Message validation des erreurs-->
                        <MultiTrigger>
                            <MultiTrigger.Conditions>
                                <Condition Property="HasText" Value="True" />
                                <Condition Property="Validation.HasError" Value="True" />
                            </MultiTrigger.Conditions>
                            <Setter Property="ToolTip" Value="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}, Path= TextError}"/>
                            <Setter Property="Validation.ErrorTemplate">
                                <Setter.Value>
                                    <ControlTemplate>
                                        <DockPanel LastChildFill="True">
                                            <Image x:Name="ValidationIcon" DockPanel.Dock="Left" Stretch="None" Width="15" Height="15" Source="pack://application:,,,/LS.Net.Telcom.Space.PropertyUI;component/Images/validationError.png" />
                                            <Border BorderBrush="Red" BorderThickness="1">
                                                <AdornedElementPlaceholder />
                                            </Border>
                                        </DockPanel>
                                    </ControlTemplate>
                                </Setter.Value>
                            </Setter>
                        </MultiTrigger>

                    </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>
</ResourceDictionary>
```

Many thanks for your help.

Comment: Since you're setting the `ControlTemplate` of the `UserControl` instead of the direct Content, I believe you may need to modify the `Binding` to travel up the template...

`Background="{TemplateBinding Background, RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}"`

Comment: Sorry but it doesn't work.

Comment: What about this...

`Background="{TemplateBinding Background, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type l:NumericTextBox}}}"`

Comment: Does uiComponent:NumericTextBox derive from TextBox ?

Comment: Yes it derive from Textbox

Comment: "Nick", I've got this error with both of your answers : The property 'RelativeSource' was not found in type 'TemplateBindingExtension'

Comment: Why did you create a CustomControl instead of just redefining a textbox's style ?

Comment: Oops, try it without the `TemplateBinding` and just regular `Binding`...

Unless I completely misunderstood what you're trying to do...

Comment: How do you apply the style you want to apply (i.e. the style with the black value) ? In another ResourceDictionnary ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I just ran a quick test with your `Style`s, and everything is working properly. For WPF `Style`s to work properly, there are a couple of things you need to do however. The first is that your custom control needs to override the `DefaultStyleKey` in its static constructor:

```
public class NumericTextBox : TextBox
{
    static NumericTextBox()
    {
        DefaultStyleKeyProperty.OverrideMetadata(
            typeof(NumericTextBox),
            new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(typeof(NumericTextBox)));
    }

    ...
}
```

The second is that your `NumericTextBox`'s default `Style` needs to be defined at a specific location in your assembly for it to be picked up. The standard location is at `Project\Themes\Generic.xaml`.

If you're still struggling with how to create custom WPF controls and styling them, here is a great introductory [CodeProject article](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/14340/Creating-a-look-less-custom-control-in-WPF).

**bgcode's comment**

TDefaultStyleKey, it is still implemented as you propose.
The second is that my NumericTextBox's style is implemented as a resourcedictionary into an other file, but I load it in constructor like that :

```
    public NumericTextBox ()
        : base()
    {
        ResourceDictionary res = Application.LoadComponent(new Uri("/MyAssemblyName;component/NumericTextBox/NumericTextBoxStyle.xaml", UriKind.RelativeOrAbsolute)) as ResourceDictionary;
        if(res != null)
            this.Resources = res;
    }
```

I think that is a good way to do too, isn't it?

**Abe Heidebrecht's response**

No. Don't do that. If you want to define the default `Style` in a separate `ResourceDictionary`, do so. Just merge it into the generic.xaml:

```
<ResourceDictionary xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
                    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml">

    <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
        <ResourceDictionary Source="MyAssemblyName;component/NumericTextBox/NumericTextBoxStyle.xaml" />
    </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>

</ResourceDictionary>
```

If you **really** don't want to have a generic.xaml, you can merge the dictionary into the `App.Resources` in your `app.xaml`. The reason why you'd prefer to put it in `generic.xaml` is that if at some point you put this control in a control's assembly, you will *need* it in `generic.xaml`, or WPF won't know where to find the default `Style`. It is better to get in the habit of doing it the right way.

Comment: Well done @Abe Heidebrecht
It works great now. I never thought this could be the problem.
Because earlier, as I started with WPF, I followed a tutorial about component creation, frameworkElement inheritance... and it was made like that : Application.LoadComponent ....
Thanks again ;)

Comment: Doing that *could* work, but I like doing as much in XAML as I can!

Answer (score 2):

I think I see what you're doing...

You're setting your Style in your ResourceDictionary and then setting the Style again somewhere else.  So, your ResourceDictionary is loading the Background in your Style so it overrides what you're setting elsewhere.

This explains why Visibility works for you because that property is not being set in the Style in your ResourceDictionary.

You should set the Style as a StaticResource and then base any later styles off of that Style.  This is basically what Sheridan suggested but you should reference the Style by a key name...

```
<Style x:Key="NumericBoxStyle" TargetType="{x:Type l:NumericTextBox}">
    <Setter Property="Background" Value="{StaticResource CustomTextBox_Background}" />
    <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="{StaticResource CustomTextBox_Border}" />
    <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{StaticResource CustomTextBox_Foreground}" />
    <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="1" />
    <Setter Property="SnapsToDevicePixels" Value="True" />
    <Setter Property="FocusVisualStyle" Value="{x:Null}"/>
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type l:NumericTextBox}">
                <Border x:Name="Border"
                  Background="{TemplateBinding Background}"
                  BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}"
                  BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}">
                    <Grid x:Name="LayoutGrid">
                        <ScrollViewer Margin="2" x:Name="PART_ContentHost" />
                    </Grid>
                </Border>
                <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                    <!--Message validation des erreurs-->
                    <MultiTrigger>
                        <MultiTrigger.Conditions>
                            <Condition Property="HasText" Value="True" />
                            <Condition Property="Validation.HasError" Value="True" />
                        </MultiTrigger.Conditions>
                        <Setter Property="ToolTip" Value="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}, Path= TextError}"/>
                        <Setter Property="Validation.ErrorTemplate">
                            <Setter.Value>
                                <ControlTemplate>
                                    <DockPanel LastChildFill="True">
                                        <Image x:Name="ValidationIcon" DockPanel.Dock="Left" Stretch="None" Width="15" Height="15" Source="pack://application:,,,/LS.Net.Telcom.Space.PropertyUI;component/Images/validationError.png" />
                                        <Border BorderBrush="Red" BorderThickness="1">
                                            <AdornedElementPlaceholder />
                                        </Border>
                                    </DockPanel>
                                </ControlTemplate>
                            </Setter.Value>
                        </Setter>
                    </MultiTrigger>

                </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

And adjust the style...

```
<Style TargetType="uiComponent:NumericTextBox" BaseOn="{StaticResource NumericBoxStyle}">
   <Setter Property="Background" Value="Black"/>
</Style>
```

Answer (score 1):

The style you define here

```
<Style TargetType="uiComponent:NumericTextBox">
   <Setter Property="Background" Value="Black"/>
</Style>
```

gets overridden by the style defined in your ResourceDictionary

If you try :

```
<uiComponent:NumericTextBox Text="{Binding myProperty}">
   <uiComponent:NumericTextBox.Style>
      <Style TargetType="uiComponent:NumericTextBox" BasedOn="{StaticResource {x:Type uiComponent:NumericTextBox}}">
         <Setter Property="Background" Value="Black"/>
      </Style>
   </uiComponent:NumericTextBox.Style>
</uiComponent:NumericTextBox>
```

.. your background should be set to black.

Answer (score -1):

How about trying this:

```
<Style TargetType="uiComponent:NumericTextBox" 
    BasedOn="{StaticResource {x:Type l:NumericTextBox}}">
    <Setter Property="Background" Value="Black"/>
</Style>
```

I'm not sure if your XML namespaces will match up, but the idea is to basically say to  WPF, 'this style is based on the default style of this type'